# PyTorch LeNet-5 do not training

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to train an adaptation of the LeNet-5 network for 1-channel images of size 30x30. Each sample matrix consists of the z-score values of some parameter for each source RGB image (size 30x30x3). Thus, along with the positive values, there are negative values.

According to this [article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/726791), I use padding for the input layer, the same layer order, and Z-score calculation for all samples, with the mean and standard deviation calculated for all samples (training and test), but the network is not training.

Here is the network code:

```
#LeNet-5 class
class Model(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.lay1_2=nn.Sequential( nn.Conv2d(1, 6, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=3), 
            nn.ReLU(), nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
        self.lay3_4=nn.Sequential( nn.Conv2d(6, 16, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=0), 
            nn.ReLU(), nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
        '2D to 1D'  
        self.trans=nn.Sequential(nn.Flatten())
        self.lay5_6 = nn.Linear(576, 100)
        self.lay7_8 = nn.Linear(100, 2)
        
        self.opt=opt.RMSprop(self.parameters(),lr=0.001,momentum=0.9) #optimizer
        self.criterion=nn.CrossEntropyLoss() #loss function - negative logarithm of likelihood
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.lay1_2(x)
        x = self.lay3_4(x)
        x = self.trans(x)
        x = self.lay5_6(x)
        return fnc.softmax(self.lay7_8(x))
```

Training parameters:

number of epochs-500, package size-50, number of classes-2.

Training main loop:

'''
for h in range(start_ep,len(epochs)):
for i in range(epochs[h]-epochs[h-1]):

```
        x1, y1 = prep_batch(train_mat,train_ans,start_posit%train_size,batch_size)
        model.opt.zero_grad()
        react=model(x1) #reaction calculation
        y1=y1.squeeze_()
        loss=model.criterion(react,y1)
        loss_copy=loss.clone() 
        loss.backward()
        model.opt.step()
        start_posit=start_posit+batch_size
    
    print('Epoch: '+str(epochs[h])+" ",end="")
    msg='Loss_train: '+str(loss_copy.detach().numpy())+" "
    print(msg,end="")
        
    #error calculation
    t_react=model(t_mat)
    t_loss=model.criterion(t_react,t_ans)
    msg='Loss_test: '+str(t_loss.detach().numpy())
    print(msg)
        
    #F-measure calculation
    t_react_n=np.argmax(t_react.detach().numpy(),axis=1)
    t_ans_n=t_ans.detach().numpy()
    F_m_res=F_mea(t_ans_n,t_react_n)
    
    #save results and model
    all_res['ep'].append(epochs[h])
    all_res['res'].append(F_m_res)
    
    checkpoint={
        'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
        'optimizer': model.opt.state_dict()
    }
    torch.save(checkpoint,os.path.join(path_nn,'model-ep'+str(epochs[h])+'.pt'))
```

'''

The learning process proceeds as follows:

[image: 2]

What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you share your training code?

Comment: plz dont define optimizer & loss function in model class

Comment: Why? I described the model class for the perceptron in the same way - the learning process was successful.

Comment: Ok, here is main training loop: